# Application of Hodge decomposition

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, hodge-theory

Hodge decomposition states any $p$ form can be decomposed into three orthogonal $L^2$ components: exact form, co-exact form and hamonic form. But actually we don't know how to decompose a general one. So how to apply the decomposition to other fields? Even if we can decompose one, what does it imply?

Comment: Dear zhangwfjh, What do you mean "other fields"?  As for applications of Hodge theory, it is a very basic tool; your question is almost as general as asking for applicaions of de Rham theory, which is to say --- it is pretty broad.  Do you know about the Lefschetz decomposition for the cohomology of smooth projecive varieties (which is one basic example)?  Regards,

Comment: @MattE I mean some "fields" that connect to physics, chemistry, biology etc, other than algebraic topology. I think it must be important to hodge theory but before I get into that, I want a more intuitive feeling about that. I don't know Leftschetz decomposition you mentioned. Thank for your comment. I would aprreciate it even if a very tiny list of applications is given.

Answer (score 10):

If $X$ is a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb C$ (equivalently,
a closed complex submanifold of $\mathbb C P^n$), then the cohomology
of $X$ (with $\mathbb C$ coeficients) has its Hodge decomposition: $H^n(X,
\mathbb C) = \oplus_{p+ q = n} H^{p,q}$; here $H^{p,q}$ consists of class that
can be represented by harmonic $(p,q)$-forms.

(The decomposition arises by combining Hodge theory as described in the OP
with extra stucture induced by the fact that $X$ is a Kahler manifold.)

One has Hodge symmetry: complex conjugation interchanges $H^{p,q}$
and $H^{q,p}$, and this implies that they have the same dimension.

The Hodge decomposition and Hodge symmery together imply, for example, that if $n$ is odd then the dimension of $H^n(X,\mathbb C)$ is even.  This is a major
topological constraint on the topology of complex projective varieties.
E.g it implies that the [Hopf surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_surface) $(\mathbb C^2 \setminus \{0\})/ 2^{\mathbb Z}$ (here $2^{\mathbb Z}$ acts by scalar multiplication), which is a compact complex manifold, can't be embedded into projective space.  (Its $H^1$ is one-dimensional.)

---

Some other example applications:

- [Lefschetz decomposition](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lefschetz_theorem)
- [Torelli theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torelli_theorem)
- Many more, but I'm going to post this now

Comment: I wish I could accept this. But I don't touch anything on algebraic geometry now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is the sort of thing you're looking for but a nice and quick application is a proof of Poincare duality: On an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$, the Hodge star operator, *, gives an isomorphism between harmonic $k$ forms and $n-k$ forms.  This is because a form $\alpha$ is harmonic if and only if $d \alpha = 0$ and $*d*\alpha = 0$.  Thus $H^k(M;\mathbb R) \simeq H^{n-k}(M;\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 2):

For the interplay of Hodge theory and physics, see various papers of Cantarella, deTurck, and Gluck.

Comment: Oh, I love those papers. Thank you very much. Glad to see relevant ones if you know more.